# Opening url in specific browser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm developing a program for my work, but am encountering a problem.

The purpose of the program, is to open different websites in a chosen browser on the click of a button. In the software, i give the user the abillity to choose whether to use chrome or IE to open the websites.

I've tried using `System.process.Start("URL")` to open websites. This works, but it opens the url in the browser which is set as default in windows.

I however, want the software to open the URLs in a user-chosen browser, by using the file path to the browser.exe - or any other way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you probably need the full path to the executable(s) to use with Process.Start.

Or they need to be on your path:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( "Firefox.exe", url );

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "http://www.somewebsite.com/");
```

see also :

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

[And Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options)

Comment: Full path may fail on x64 PCs, correct path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox
better to use the short version above.